# Azure DB Backup Using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I've read a number of articles here, but, really haven't come across a solution.

I'm using SSMS 2016 to manually back up a Azure DB on a regular basis.  I do this through the Generate Scripts option.  I have not attempted to restore from this data yet, but, have validated the SQL and it appears good.

Question, while I still need to validate, should I be able to backup an Azure SQL DB from SSMS and restore using this same tool?  Is there a better tool I can use to do this?